# Como eu retiro caracteres de uma string até certo ponto? em PHP

Tags: php, string

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$numeros = "142-22";
```

Preciso apenas do "142" e quero ignorar o resto "-22".
Como eu faço isso?

Saída esperada:

```
$numeros = "142-22";
$num = "142";
```

Existe alguma função que eu possa utilizar?

Answer (score 4):

O PHP já tem função própria para isso:

```
$final = strstr($numeros,'-',true);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/f2d1hA)**.

> Manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stristr.php

Tem outras maneiras:

```
$final = explode('-',$numeros)[0];
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/VKvFuM)**.

> Manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

Usando o explode:

```
$string = "142-22";
// da um explode usando o - como separador
$stringSeparada = explode("-", $string);
// a $stringSeparada vira uma array, e i primeiro elemento dessa array é a parte inicial antes do caractere -
echo $stringSeparada[0];
```

Comment: Não entendi o negativo na sua, de qq forma eu já tinha dado +1 (praticamente postamos junto, e é a mesma solução da minha 2a alternativa - tecnicamente vc até postou antes do meu edit, se for "cronometrar")

Comment: Também não entendi... é a vida!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [substr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> substr — Retorna uma parte de uma string
>
> Fonte: [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

```
$string = "142-22";

echo substr($string, 0, 3);
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de7c9fa1686d4a2dbb00c57bcb39ee79b9bdd64b)

Answer (score 0):

```
$numeros = "142-22";
$num = substr($numeros,0,strpos($numeros,"-"));
echo $num;
```

Eu usei o `substr()` para trazer os caracteres do primeiro até a posição que o for encontrado o "-", o bom dessa maneira é que não importa quantos caracteres tem antes do "-" ele sempre vai trazer tudo.

Abraço espero ter ajudado.